# Spring batch infinite step

Tags: spring-batch, etl

I want to read data from my DB (MySQL) do some processing and then write the result to kafka.

Is it a good practice to use spring batch for infinite chunked step?
keep reading the data from the database for ever? (The database is active during batch processing since it a db of web app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch processing is about fixed, finite data sets. You seem to be looking for a streaming solution, which is out of scope of Spring Batch.